# Не запускается контейнер (docker)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Только-только начал изучать docker. Написал апишку для сайта на ASP.NET + MySQL, пытаюсь завернуть проект в контейнер: создаю образ, контейнер и запускаю его. Открываю localhost и выводится ошибка HTTP ERROR 500, а также в терминале появляется такое сообщение:[image: ошибка в терминале]

Dockerfile: [image: dockerfile]

docker-compose.yml: [image: docker-compose.yml]

А если билдить контейнер через docker-compose, то получается вот это: [image: docker-compose]

**ПОМОГИТЕ**

Comment: Писать веб апи на asp... скажем так, я не спец, но это ппц...) по логам у вас ошибка сертификата

Comment: @Jour а что не так с asp?

Comment: @Jour тот сайт, на котором ты щас сидишь, написан на ASP.NET :)

Comment: прошу меня простить, я не против ASP... я просто его не знаю + предвзято отношусь к Win... я имею ввиду, что вашу задачу возможно будет проще решить иначе с затратой меньших усилий

Comment: @Jour да ну, на asp все довольно лаконично и красиво происходит. Для решения одной и той же задачи на asp потребуется меньше времени и ресурсов чем на том же php